# Yahoo media player not working with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio

I have a yahoo media player embedded in my webpage. I am currently using Ruby on Rails to create/edit my web page. When i click the play button next to a track the YMP waits a while and then goes to the next track without playing the first one. I then get a warning on my second (last) track that its file could not be found.

Does anyone has a better recommendation for an audio player or a way to fix this one?

Comment: We'll need to see sample code and/or a live demo to help debug your Yahoo Media Player problem (although it sounds like the path to your audio file might be wrong, so I'd double check that as a starting point). You might also like to consider [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) as an alternative option to YMP.

Comment: i have trippled checked my path. In fact i dragged the file into Terminal so that i got the exact path without typing it, but its still not running correctly. And the code is on Yahoo Media Player.com its just 2 very easy lines of code. But i am thinking jPlayer my be my best bet now

Comment: I've discovered that Yahoo Media Player doesn't work when testing audio/html files locally with `file:///` style URLs. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments above, it sounds like you're testing Yahoo Media Player on a Mac by double clicking the .html file, resulting in a URL like `file:///path/to/your/file.html`, or using the built-in Ruby on Rails test server.

Having tried it myself, that doesn't work. Yahoo Media Player only loads correctly when the URL in your browser's address bar starts with `http://` **and when the audio/video file is hosted on a remote server.**

I suggest that you either:

1. Upload your html/RoR app and audio file to a remote server and adjust the mp3 path accordingly;

   -- or --
2. Upload the audio file to a remote server (it will not work if stored locally), update the audio file's path, and browse to your local RoR test URL to try it. (If you're not using the Rails test server, you'll need to host the html file locally in your `/~Sites/` directory, turn Web Sharing on, and browse to 'http://localhost/~User/test.html` to test it.)

Comment: ok i understand what you are saying, but how do you strewam audio from remote servers. For example if i wanted to stream audio from youtube all i would have to do is copy the URL, but how would i stream an audio loop from say 
"looperman" (http://www.looperman.com/tracks.php) which has several loops on one page where i can't just use the URL

Comment: Yahoo Media Player automatically creates a playlist for all the audio files you link to. If you want more specific control over audio playback, use jPlayer. Be sure that you have permission to link to and play any audio for remote sites you use. Hotlinking files without permission is bad netiquette.